# Getting zero as previous level in multilevel list (InDesign CS3)

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have created three paragraph styles: "Título" as a first-level category, "SubTítulo" as the second-level category and "SubSubTítulo" as the third-level category.

"SubTítulo" is based on "Título", and "SubSubTítulo" is based on "SubTítulo". They all belong to a list called "Títulos".

While the second-level category works fine, the third-level one interprets the second-level category as non-existant I think.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEQEI.png]

And the third-level category configuration:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukihl.png]

I want my list to look like:

2. Documentación

2.1 Conceptos básicos

2.1.1 Composición

2.1.2 Aplicación en el cómic

Instead of:

2. Documentación

2.1 Conceptos básicos

2.0.1 Composición

2.0.2 Aplicación en el cómic

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry.. where do you want to restart the numbering?

Comment: If you are asking because the "Restart numbers at this level after any previous level" is checked, I didn't really understood what the option does so I tried checking and unchecking it. Right now it's unchecked at every level except the first but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce this problem in ID CS6 or CC based on your settings in the screenshot. Be sure that each of the level two and three list paragraph styles is "Based On" the style for the previous level, and that all of them point to the same named list.

If those settings are correct, then save the document as IDML (File>Save and choose the IDML file type) then create a new InDesign document from the saved IDML. This will clear out any internal errors that may have built up while you were editing the document. (For CS3 and below, File>Export to .INX and create the new INDD from the saved INX.)

If after all that, you still see the error, delete your InDesign preferences (hold down Ctl-Alt-Shift/Cmd-Opt-Shift while ID is starting) and see if that doesn't clear the problem.

And if after all of that it's *still* not right, send me the file (gngcreative@gmail.com) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for answering Alan. I'm using CS3 and it doesn't seem to allow saving as IDML. I've checked the parameters several times to make sure that they're right. I also tried your other option to no avail. I think I'll try sending the file to you and see if you can spot the problem, sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: See my addition to the answer, in that case.

Comment: The .INX solution worked, thank you very much!!! I'd been dealing with this issue for hours!

Comment: Keep this as a useful tool. When something seems to be weird with an InDesign document, especially one you've been working on for a while with lots of edits, exporting as .INX and recreating the document will often handle the problem. If you check, you'll see that your new file is also quite a bit smaller than the old one -- another benefit. Glad to help.